# Preparing a data frame with multiple nodes in a single column for use in igraph

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

I have a data frame approximately formatted like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    x = c(
        "Ben, Ellen", 
        "BV, Ellen, Trev", 
        "Ben, Trev, Pat", 
        "Ellen, Ben", 
        "Ev, Ryan"))
```

Where each observation is a group of nodes (friends).

I want to `igraph` the data but I'm assuming it needs to look like this first:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    x = c(
        "Ben","BV","BV","Ellen","Ben",
        "Ben","Trev","Ellen","Ev"),
    y = c(
        "Ellen","Ellen","Trev","Trev","Trev",
        "Pat","Pat","Ben","Ryan"))
```

How can I string split each observation and ensure that each node (friend) is linked with every other node in observation? Basically, how can I turn `df1` into `df2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to use base functions

```
ss <- strsplit(as.character(df1$x),", ")
el <- do.call("rbind", Map(function(x) t(combn(x,2)), ss))
```

with your data that returns

```
      [,1]    [,2]   
 [1,] "Ben"   "Ellen"
 [2,] "BV"    "Ellen"
 [3,] "BV"    "Trev" 
 [4,] "Ellen" "Trev" 
 [5,] "Ben"   "Trev" 
 [6,] "Ben"   "Pat"  
 [7,] "Trev"  "Pat"  
 [8,] "Ellen" "Ben"  
 [9,] "Ev"    "Ryan"
```

and you can plot that with igraph

```
plot(graph_from_edgelist(el))
```

[image]

Comment: "It may be easier to use base" - lies! ;-) Or even `t(do.call(cbind,lapply(ss,combn,2)))`

Comment: Works perfect, and scales to observations with more than 3 nodes! Thank you!